# Why is php skipping the if statement?

Tags: php

The basics of what I want to do is check the user values.

If they are there return `true` and go back to the page otherwise return `false` and print null values.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * from Users where username = ? and password = ?");
$params1 = array( $username, $password);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params1);
if ($stmt === false) 
{
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$Users = array();

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $username1 = $row['username'];
    $password1= $row['password'];
}


$Users["username"] = $username1;
$Users["password"] = $password1;

//echo json_encode($Users);
echo "you are here";

if ($username1==null)
{
    return false;
    echo "null values";
}
else {
    return true;
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))
        header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    else
        echo "No referrer.";
}
echo "\n\nyou're at the end though";

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

sqlsrv_close( $conn );

}    
else {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

As you can see I am trying to debug the program and see where the program is going. It gets to the point

```
//echo json_encode($Users);
echo "you are here";
```

After that nothing else seems to work and I don't know why.

Comment: why you using ``return false;`` or ``true`` in the if block?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and setup xdebug and then step through your code. echo or var_dump driven debugging gets tiresome fast and messes up your codebase with unnecessary statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Directly after your working `echo` you have:

```
if ($username1==null)
{
    return false;
    ...
}
else
{
    return true;
    ...
}

...
```

So nothing after this will get executed because of the `return` statements. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call. return also ends the execution of an
>   eval() statement or script file.
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script
>   file is ended.

Also note that you should check for the number of rows returned from your query, now you will get `undefined variable` warnings if no row was found.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect the page and return true or false to that page then?

Comment: @EoinÓCribín Sure, you could use a header redirect. Something like: `header('Location:some_page.php?result=true/false'); exit;`. If that is what you mean of course.

Comment: that works but I'm trying to refer back to the page that sent the request in the first place is there a variable that stores this?

Comment: @EoinÓCribín Not really, html is stateless. You can store things in for example a session but then the information would be share between different tabs where the same site is open. An alternative would be to make an ajax call so that the user never leaves the page in the first place.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it and find a way around it. I'm using ionic and making it as a phone app so it's not really browsers but same idea applies I guess!

Answer (score 1):

before you enter thw while statment you need to check the row count in if statment if its not 0 return true else return false something like this

```
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt)
{
// your code be here 
return true;
}else{
// your code be here 
return false;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php

Comment: looks good! Any idea how to return true to the page that orignally sent the request so I can use that as a variable?

Comment: I think if you try to use this code as function will be good and easy to use i mean $result = fucttionname($username,$password); and in this function write your code